Ros2 bag timestamp time source
Main question:
What time source does ros2 bag record use by default to stamp each of its received/logged messages? Is it correct that this is the computer's system time? The ros2bag README mentions that one the --use-sim-time flag is not set, the system clock will be used.
Background:
We have a robot where we occasionally seem to lose communication with the actuators. During these approximately 0.5 seconds, the drives enter a damped mode because they no longer receive commands, and the robot slowly starts to collapse. After this time window, communication seems to be restored, and the robot moves again according to our commands.
When inspecting the bags that were recorded during these events, there appears no gap in the data. Instead, the joint position data jumps instantaneously from the joint position before the communication loss to the joint position after the communication loss. I adapted the script from here to inspect the rosbag data in detail. This also shows that around the communication loss, subsequent samples in the bag indeed show a discrete jump in the recorded joint position, but the bag message timestamps (the ones used by ros2 bag, NOT the ones that might be present inside the message headers) show a normal continuation of time, with the normal interval of 2 ms between messages. (Furthermore, messages that do contain a header with timestamp data also show no discreet jumps around the "communication loss" event).
EDIT:
The two plots below show rosbag2 joint position data for one of the robot's joints. The second plot shows the same event, but zoomed in more to see the individual messages.


Analysis question:
If:

the ros2 bag recording program stamps all received messages with system time,
and at a certain event the time in the real world has obviously advanced by about 0.5 seconds,
but the bag data timestamps show no jump when comparing the datapoints before and after this event,

Should we then logically conclude that during these 0.5 seconds, on the computer running both the control nodes and the bag recording, the system time also froze for 0.5? This sort of temporary freezing of the entire computer would obviously explain a communication timeout with the robot actuators, but it also seems like an extreme conclusion.

Refer to this previous question for more info on rosbag timestamps.
It is for ROS Melodic, but I assume the logic has not changed.
Apart from that:
Given you have continuous time stamps, I would rather conclude that your computer did not freeze. If your computer froze, I'd rather expect both a jump in time as well as in joint position?
I suggest to use a tool like PlotJuggler to visualize your data during execution. A 0,5 sec delay should be easily visible...

JRTG, thanks for your reply and thinking along. However, the page you shared does not discuss where rosbag2 actually gets its timestamp from. The rosbag2 README mentions that when --use-sim-time is not set, then the system clock will be used for the stamps. But that would make the data I have collected quite strange.
I have edited my original post to add the plots from Plotjuggler. There is a jump in joint position data during which the robot moved in the real world, but from the perspective of the rosbag no time passed passed during this event, instead of showing 0.5 seconds of no data.

What I rather meant is to use Plotjuggler to directly visualize the data (i.e. topic messages) during execution, instead of writing the data into a rosbag and investigating that. That way, you avoid possible issues with the rosbag.

Also: what hardware are you running on? Even if a CPU freezes, generally the hardware clock keeps running, so as I wrote: if your computer froze, I'd rather expect both a jump in time as well as in joint position?
